# Is there an easy way to remember the rotation methods for red-black trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree

Is there an easy way to remember the rotation methods for red-black trees?

Comment: I don't see a point in forcing yourself to remember them. If you use red-black trees a lot then you will eventually know them by heart. If you don't then why force yourself to remember them? Just look them up whenever you need them. Also, I suggest looking into treaps. They are very efficient and have only two rotation types.

Comment: This has been used as an interview question.

Comment: Move on to the next interview. Nobody will ask it to you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. There is no way to remember!!** (Well, not really, but it is the most appropriate answer with regards to your use of your own time).

You know what? Nobody *needs* to be able to recite the exact mechanics of the rotations. *Not even the handful of people required to implement these, need to remember them!* See [Java's implementation of TreeMap](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/TreeMap.java.htm), which is a red-black tree, and search for "From CLR". They basically copy-pasted the code, **which is exactly the proper course of action here**.

Comment: well there actually is: if you search for 2-3-4 tree and btree

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps they are looking for the equivalence of 2-3-4 trees (B-trees of degree 2) and red-black trees?

I have always found insertion in B-Trees easier to understand than insertion in red-black trees.

See the page here: http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/fall95/cs660/notes/RedBlackTree/RedBlack.html

In any case, you can probably just derive the rotations needed on the spot, it is not really that hard, once you have been familiar with them.